# ImportError: cannot import name '_obtain_input_shape' in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I try to import keras_squeezenet I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/belog/drone_sees/train_model.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras_squeezenet import SqueezeNet
  File "C:\Users\belog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras_squeezenet\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras_squeezenet.squeezenet import SqueezeNet
  File "C:\Users\belog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras_squeezenet\squeezenet.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
ImportError: cannot import name '_obtain_input_shape'
```

Here is the import code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras_squeezenet import SqueezeNet
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Convolution2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Sequential
```

How to fix it? (I'm using tensorflow==2.6.2, keras==2.6.0, keras-squeezenet==0.4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried the new version ? (see : https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-squeezenet)

you can install it with : 
pip install git+https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-squeezenet.git

Answer (score 0):

in the new versions of tensor flow there is nothing called
_obtain_input_shape
there is only preprocess_input
so change from this

`from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape`

```
to this 

from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
```